# Clicking link in gallery causes page to 'jump'?

Tags: jquery, html, css, gallery

Please excuse the poorly worded title, hopefully I can explain the issue here.

I've written a simple gallery control in jQuery, there's six images with two button controls that allow the user to cycle through a total collection of images. I have this part working fine but whenever I click a button to move through the collection the page 'jumps/scrolls' automatically to the top of the page? I've tried giving the gallery container a fixed height as I had a similar issue before which I managed to solve doing this but this hasn't helped:

Here is the jQuery:

```
var index = 0;
$(function () {
    $('#btnLeft').click(function () {
        if (index != 0) {
            index--;
            $('#sixth').attr('src', $('#fifth').attr('src'));
            $('#fifth').attr('src', $('#fourth').attr('src'));
            $('#fourth').attr('src', $('#third').attr('src'));
            $('#third').attr('src', $('#second').attr('src'));
            $('#second').attr('src', $('#first').attr('src'));
            $('#first').attr('src', '/Content/Images/Gallery/Thumbs/' + parseInt(index + 1) + '.png');
        }
    });

    $('#btnRight').click(function () {
        if (parseInt(6 + index) != 10) {
            index++;
            $('#first').attr('src', $('#second').attr('src'));
            $('#second').attr('src', $('#third').attr('src'));
            $('#third').attr('src', $('#fourth').attr('src'));
            $('#fourth').attr('src', $('#fifth').attr('src'));
            $('#fifth').attr('src', $('#sixth').attr('src'));
            $('#sixth').attr('src', '/Content/Images/Gallery/Thumbs/' + parseInt(6 + index) + '.png');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the markup:

```
<div id="gallerySlider" style="height: 160px;">
    <img id="first" src="/Content/Images/Gallery/Thumbs/1.png" alt="Image" width="160" height="160" style="float:left;" /> 
    <img id="second" src="/Content/Images/Gallery/Thumbs/2.png" alt="Image" width="160" height="160" style="float:left;" />
    <img id="third" src="/Content/Images/Gallery/Thumbs/3.png" alt="Image" width="160" height="160" style="float:left;" />
    <img id="fourth" src="/Content/Images/Gallery/Thumbs/4.png" alt="Image" width="160" height="160" style="float:left;" />
    <img id="fifth" src="/Content/Images/Gallery/Thumbs/5.png" alt="Image" width="160" height="160" style="float:left;" />
    <img id="sixth" src="/Content/Images/Gallery/Thumbs/6.png" alt="Image" width="160" height="160" style="float:left;" />

    <a id="btnLeft" style="position:relative; float:left; bottom:105px;" href="#"><img src="/Content/Images/Design/leftbutton.png" alt="Left Button" /></a>
    <a id="btnRight" href="#" style="position:relative; float:right; bottom:105px;"><img src="/Content/Images/Design/rightbutton.png" alt="Right Button" /></a>
</div>
```

Can anyone offer advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) like following to stop browser default load and jump:

```
$('#btnLeft').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        if (index != 0) {
            index--;
            $('#sixth').attr('src', $('#fifth').attr('src'));
            $('#fifth').attr('src', $('#fourth').attr('src'));
            $('#fourth').attr('src', $('#third').attr('src'));
            $('#third').attr('src', $('#second').attr('src'));
            $('#second').attr('src', $('#first').attr('src'));
            $('#first').attr('src', '/Content/Images/Gallery/Thumbs/' + parseInt(index + 1) + '.png');
        }
    });

    $('#btnRight').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        if (parseInt(6 + index) != 10) {
            index++;
            $('#first').attr('src', $('#second').attr('src'));
            $('#second').attr('src', $('#third').attr('src'));
            $('#third').attr('src', $('#fourth').attr('src'));
            $('#fourth').attr('src', $('#fifth').attr('src'));
            $('#fifth').attr('src', $('#sixth').attr('src'));
            $('#sixth').attr('src', '/Content/Images/Gallery/Thumbs/' + parseInt(6 + index) + '.png');
        }
    });
```

Comment: To clarify: use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the browser from attempting to load the link, which is causing your jump.